# getIFPPlanQuotes - Filters and Maximum Page Size

Tags: medical, healthcare-finder-api

I need below clarifications regarding these two APIs (getIFPPlanQuotes & getSMGPlanQuotes):

1- Can filter criteria be sent in request?
2- What maximum page size can be returned?